# Subquery in IN does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using TransactSQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2014) and here's my problem:
I'm using the standard "Northwind" database for practice and I wanted to see a list of Categories that don't have any Products.

Firstly I created a new Category, which wouldn't have any Products:

```
insert into Categories (CategoryName) values ('TestCategory')
```

Then I wrote this:

```
  SELECT CategoryName 
  FROM Categories
  WHERE CategoryID NOT IN (select CategoryID from Products)
```

Unfortunately it gives nothing.

Here's how I understand it:
I want to find categories without products connected with them, so I used
`WHERE CategoryID NOT IN (select CategoryID from Products)`, because I want to compare every CategoryID from Categories table with a list which I get from `select CategoryID from Products` - this list includes every category that HAS products. So I think that using NOT IN should let me to see categories that don't have any products.

I hope you understood what I was trying to describe. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: Can you confirm your 'TestCategory' is actually there?  (ie. was your insert statement committed)?

Comment: Yeah, it surely is, answers below fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` is not a good construct.  If any of the returned values from the subquery are `NULL`, then it never returns any rows.  A naive way to fix this is to use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT CategoryName 
FROM Categories
WHERE CategoryID NOT IN (select CategoryID from Products where CategoryId IS NOT NULL);
```

A better way to fix it is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName 
FROM Categories c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Products p
                  WHERE p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
                 );
```

This behaves in a more intuitive manner.

Note that this behavior is ANSI standard behavior.  When a `NULL` value is present, then the engine does not know if `c.categoryId` is in the list.  Hence, it returns `NULL` which is treated as false.

Answer (score 2):

Sql works on three value based logic.Your table must contains null in category ID column thats why its not displaying anything,Modify subquery as

```
 SELECT CategoryName 
  FROM Categories
  WHERE CategoryID NOT IN (select CategoryID from Products where catogoryID is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution:

```
select CategoryName from Categories c LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p
ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
where ProductName is null
```

I think that answers above are more intuitive, but I just wanted to show another way of handling this.